# Echarts-for-react using a navbar for sunburst charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I am using a sunburst chart to display data, however I want to be able to navigate to the children of the root via a navbar. My problem is that I don't understand how to pass the "navigation" command into the sunburst chart. How do I write a function that lets me change child via a button?

This is the code, the "ASD" gets logged but it still navigates

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ReactECharts from "echarts-for-react";
import * as echarts from "echarts";

const SunburstChart = ({ data }) => {
     const chartRef = useRef(null);
     const [options, setOptions] = useState({});
     const [selectedNode, setSelectedNode] = useState(null);

     useEffect(() => {
        const chart = chartRef.current.getEchartsInstance();
        setOptions(getOptions());
      }, [data]);

     const getOptions = () => {
       const getChildren = (children) => {
         return children.map((child) => {
            return {
              ...child,
              itemStyle: {
                color: child.color || "#ddd",
                borderWidth: 2,
              },
              children: child.children ? getChildren(child.children) : undefined,
                };
              });
            };

            return {
              visualMap: {
                type: 'continuous',
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                left: 'left',
                calculable: false,
                orient: 'vertical',
              
            
                
                inRange: {
                  color: ['#2F93C8', '#AEC48F', '#FFDB5C', '#F98862']
                }
              },
              series: {
                radius: ["0%", "95%"],
                type: "sunburst",
                sort: undefined,
               
                data: getChildren(data),
                label: {
                  rotate: "radial",
                },
             
                levels: [],
                itemStyle: {
                  color: "#ddd",
                  borderWidth: 2,
                },
              },
            };
          };


          const eventsMap =(childNode)=>{
            const chartInstance = chartRef.current.getEchartsInstance();
            console.log("ASD")
            chartInstance.dispatchAction({
              type: "select",
              seriesId: chilNode,
            })
          };
          
          return (
               <div>
                  <ReactECharts
                   ref={chartRef}
                   echarts={echarts}
                   option={options}
                   style={{ height: "500px", width: "100%" }}/>
               
                   <button onClick=(eventsMap("Flora_1")>Flora 1</button>
                   <button onClick=(eventsMap("Flora_2"))>Flora 2</button>
                   <button onClick=(eventsMap("Flora_3")>Flora 3</button>

                </div>
              
          );
        };

        SunburstChart.propTypes = {
          data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        };

        export default SunburstChart;
```

I tried sending a chartInstance.dispatchAction to navigate into the sunburst but doesnt matter how many tries i do i cant get it to do what i want.